# Parsing R.java back to xml files

Tags: java, android, android-layout, syntax, xml-parsing

I have an `R.java` file, but I lost the corresponding XML files. Is there a tool that could parse the `R.java` and translate the fields back to XML attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from doccumentation: 
*Once you provide a resource in your application , you can apply it by referencing its resource ID. All resource IDs are defined in your project's R class, which the aapt tool automatically generates.

When your application is compiled, aapt generates the R class, which contains resource IDs for all the resources in your res/ directory. For each type of resource, there is an R subclass (for example, R.drawable for all drawable resources), and for each resource of that type, there is a static integer (for example, R.drawable.icon). This integer is the resource ID that you can use to retrieve your resource.

Although the R class is where resource IDs are specified, **you should never need to look there to discover a resource ID.***

To put it simple you use this class to access resources. You **CANNOT** translate auto generated indexes to XML attributes.

Comment: Is it possible that the R.class may generate fields from entities that are not found in my XML files, specifically those in my /res folder of the project?

Comment: For example if you delete entity in XML file their id's are automatically deleted from R.java during compilation. So if the XML files are missing, and project builds, all of their entities must be deleted by default. If you add XML files to project, all indexes must be auto generated during compilation either.

Comment: I rephrase, would a R.class in a dex of an APK file have fields that would tally the mapping of all the required XML attributes in the /res directory of an APK file?

Comment: If project builds then the answer is yes.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, R.java file only contains auto generated indexes for the resources so I am sure it's not possible to get back XML files out of it and so not sure about if any tools available to do so.